# how to create dropdown menu in joomla

Tags: javascript, css, drop-down-menu, joomla

Hi I am looking to find out how i can create a menu like the one found on the following site:

[http://www.boo-burger.com/]

I am currently creating a new site in Joomla and would love to learn how i could create something like this. Would love to learn, so would be happy if somebody could advise.

I am aware of icemegamenu and other addons that create a responsive menu, but I like how this is animated and also doesnt take up the full width of the mobile page.

Answer (score 0):

At first point that website is created in WordPress.

Comment: lol budrys, thanks for your response. I was looking for some help as to how this could be done in joomla. another example is [https://www.gbk.co.uk/]

Comment: Hi, wanted to update my original question, as I found a link to RokNavMenu and also the following URL that had a guide to help me get this setup [https://www.joomlalondon.co.uk/jugl-blog/how-to/how-to-create-a-mobile-hamburger-menu-for-joomla-default-template-protostar]. Hope this helps anybody that may have the same issue.